# I'm trying to use wmic to find a specific USB drive and then set an environment variable

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, find, wmic

I can find the drive with the following `wmic` command:

```
wmic logicaldisk where VolumeName='USB-BACKUP' get deviceid |find /v "DeviceID"
```

it returns `Q:` and that works a treat.  However, I also want to, *at the same time*, set the Drive letter returned to an environment variable. I reviewed how to set one with `wmic`, but couldn't find how to combine it into a combined single command.

This is probably more than is needed for this post since what I really want is:
One combined `wmic` command to set the environment variable based on the found USB drive.

All the following was a kludge in an attempt to get this to work. I resorted to sending it to a text file and then reading it into an environment variable via:

```
wmic logicaldisk where VolumeName='USB-BACKUP' get deviceid |find /v "DeviceID" >c:\Util\DrvLtr.txt

set /p DrvLtr=<c:\UTIL\DrvLtr.txt
```

Which appears on the surface to work.  However, the resultant text file actually has an additional 8 erroneous invisible characters and a couple of extra CR/LF to boot. I feared this would cause problems later and sure enough, it does.

Using the trashed text file, it will do a simple `dir %DrvLtr%` and that works. However, if I do something like:

```
if not (%DrvLtr%)==() echo %DrvLtr%
```

it shows the following error:

> )==() was unexpected at this time.

I verified it errors out due to the trash in the text file. It works fine if I create a text file via Notepad with simply `Q:` in it (and of course, the requisite CR/LF pair that notepad adds when you save it.)

Not to get sidetracked though. The original goal still stands: Find the USB drive letter and put it in an environment variable.

"Why," you ask? This is for unattended backup routine and you cant count on the USB being on a particular drive on multiple machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `"usebackq tokens=2 delims=="` or `` `/format:list ^| find /I "DeviceID" ``...

```bat
for /f %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where VolumeName^='USB-BACKUP' get deviceid^|find ":"')do set "_DrvLtr=%%a" && call echo\%_DrvLtr%
```

Comment: Wow this site is great!  Ask a question and get a really swift good answer.  Add more to the question and get another great answer.  Thank you all for helping.  This answer is everything I needed and the kitchen sink.  I'm guessing you added the _ to my environment variable because that is the convention?   Thanks

Comment: @WithaKay Yes, see: The first character of the name must not be numeric. It is a common practice to prefix variable names with either an undescore or a dollar sign _variable or $variable, these prefixes are not required but help to prevent any confusion with the standard built-in Windows Environment variables or any other command strings. **[Here: `set` ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (`wmic logicaldisk where "VolumeName='USB-BACKUP'" get deviceid /format:list ^| find /I "DeviceID"`) do set "DrvLtr=%%a"
```

You can use `/format:list` to show like `DeviceId=Q:` format and easily parse using `for /f`.

Comment: Hi Wasif  Thanks for taking the time to consider this problem.  I can see you have a better handle on this than I, but the command as given seems to have a problem.  When I try it it reports:        USB-BACKUP - Invalid alias verb.

Comment: @WithaKey quote the part like "VolumeName='USB-BACKUP'"

Comment: Hi again Wasif  That of course did the trick.  I'm still learning how to use this forum and lost most of my previous comment in a edit, but you were able to figure it out anyway,    I am grateful for the time you offered.  It was a real help.  Thanks & stay safe.

Comment: Edited, please click the big tick mark!

Comment: I normally eschew any form of social interaction online, so I don't really know the proper etiquette, but I do understand that marking the correct answer has value.   I tried to uptick your answer, but since I was a guest sign in it didn't work.  So I created an account,  Then it said until I had 15 points my upticks were not shown.  I tried.

Comment: @Withakey click the right mark

Comment: I guess I dont know what the right mark is.  I click the UP arrow just above the big "0" score.  and when I do it says "  Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."  seems pretty clear that they want a new user to have more time/posts before they are considered a bonafide member.

Comment: I hope I have managed to check all the right boxes now.  May I posit that it is possible to concatenate a redirection. Something like this doesn't work,  for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (`wmic logicaldisk where  "VolumeName='USB-BACKUP'" get deviceid /format:list ^| find /I "DeviceID"`) do set "DrvLtr=%%a" echo %DrvLtr% > c:\util\DrvLtr.txt    but I'm eager to learn from those of your ilk.